# Adobe reader x64 missing dependencies

Tags: dependencies, adobe-reader

I get the error after executing `acroread`:

```
acroread: error while loading shared libraries:
libxml2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Additionally (for me) sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 installs a zillion i386 packages, but hey, we want to be able to run adobe-still-32bits-in-2014 code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing libxml2 library. Install it from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2
```

Comment: to be exact...  I tried to install the x32 version and noticed a few packages, that were not installed on default for x64 system.  One of them was libxml2 :)

Answer (score 17):

You need to install the libs:32. 
Execute these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386
sudo apt-get install libxml2:i386
```

Comment: I wish Adobe would make packages that don't suck.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to making sure libxml2 is installed and depending on which version of Ubuntu you are running -- I upgraded from 10.04 to 12.04 -- you also might need to have ia32-libs installed as noted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219631/cannot-open-adobe-reader-on-ubuntu-12-10-64bits).