# Cannot open adobe reader on Ubuntu 12.10 64bits

Tags: adobe-reader

I downloaded `AdbeRdr9.5.1-1_i386linux_enu.deb` from the official website and installed it. Nothing wrong happened during the installation. But when I click Adobe Reader's icon, it has no response. Neither can I open a pdf file with Adobe Reader.

I checked that the package name is `adobereader-enu:i386`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First Install  ***ia32-libs***  package from ubuntu-software-center, then reinstall adobe reader.

Comment: This was a wonderful answer. Thanks. The error is misleading and makes one think that libxml2 isn't installed. It was on my system, but not the ia32-libs package.

Answer (score -1):

if you have a 64bit system, do not forget to install also this package libxml2:i386

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2:i386
```

Otherwise, acroread will fail

```
acroread: error while loading shared libraries: libxml2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

http://www.lorenzobettini.it/2012/11/install-adobe-reader-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal-64bit/