# Cannot open Adobe Reader

Tags: installation, adobe

I have installed Adobe Reader a few times, but it will not open on its own when clicked, nor can I open it when I download a file and open with Adobe Reader.  Nothing happens, not even an error message.

This thread seems to have the answer: [Cannot open adobe reader on Ubuntu 12.10 64bits](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219631/cannot-open-adobe-reader-on-ubuntu-12-10-64bits/219636#219636)

However, when I try to download ia32-libs I get the following error message: This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

How can I figure out what software packages I need to download first?

Or is there another way to do this?

**I have already installed libxml2.**

Comment: How did you install adobe reader?

Answer (score 0):

Following these steps worked for me (Adobe Reader 9 on Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS 64 bit):

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y acroread-bin
sudo apt-get install -y acroread
```

(mostly based on http://www.unixmen.com/install-adobe-reader-9-in-ubuntu/)