# Troubleshooting blank LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: 12.04, configuration, shared-library

Today I installed Acrobat Reader from the website, but it fails to run.  When I try to run it from the command line, I get:

```
jdibling@hurricane /opt/Adobe/Reader9/bin $ ./acroread 
/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread: error while loading shared libraries: libxml2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However, libxml2 is installed and in the expected location:

```
root@hurricane /usr # find . -name "libxml2.so.2"
./lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2
```

I noticed that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set:

```
jdibling@hurricane /opt/Adobe/Reader9/bin $ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

jdibling@hurricane /opt/Adobe/Reader9/bin $
```

I'm guessing that this is either the problem, or an indicator of the problem.

I'm not super familiar with how this variable is set under Ubuntu, but I have an inkling that is is done via `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` in some way:

```
root@hurricane /etc/ld.so.conf.d # grep "lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" *
x86_64-linux-gnu.conf:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
x86_64-linux-gnu.conf:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
root@hurricane /etc/ld.so.conf.d #
```

The chance that at some point I broke my system is greater than zero, but I'm lost as to where to go from here to troubleshoot and fix this problem.  What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

A blank `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` isn't the problem.
It's not set by default in Ubuntu.

Per [the comment on the answer on this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144721/adobe-reader-x64-missing-dependencies), it seems most likely that you installed the 64bit version of the library but you're running a 32bit application and therefore need the 32bit lib too.

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2:i386
```

Comment: Hmm.  I did that and now it's complaining that `libstdc++.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64`

Comment: I don't know what to say. I [downloaded](ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/) and installed the deb, installed, and it ran fine.

Comment: I'm continuing to research.  If I figure it out I'll let you know.

Comment: Problem solved.  It turned out not to be `libxml` at all (apparently), but `ia32-libs`.  [This question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/219631/cannot-open-adobe-reader-on-ubuntu-12-10-64bits) is a direct duplicate.  I can't vote to close my own question.  Can you close as dupe?